# I can't move with joystick and shoot at the same time

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, touch, game-engine

I have a little problem here, when I move with joystick I can't shoot while moving but  when I move I'm able to look around with rest of the screen touch, like most fps games on android do, so How can I shoot while moving or while look around...

This script helps me shoot

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SimpleShoot : MonoBehaviour
{

public GameObject bulletPrefab;
public GameObject casingPrefab;
public GameObject muzzleFlashPrefab;
public Transform barrelLocation;
public Transform casingExitLocation;


public float shotPower = 100f;

void Start()
{
    if (barrelLocation == null)
        barrelLocation = transform;
    Input.multiTouchEnabled = true;
}

void Update()
{

}

public void Fire()
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
    {
        GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("Fire");
    }
}

void Shoot()
{
    //  GameObject bullet;
    //  bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, barrelLocation.position, 
barrelLocation.rotation);
    // bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(barrelLocation.forward * 
shotPower);

    GameObject tempFlash;
   Instantiate(bulletPrefab, barrelLocation.position, 
barrelLocation.rotation).GetComponent<Rigidbody> 
().AddForce(barrelLocation.forward * shotPower);
       tempFlash = Instantiate(muzzleFlashPrefab, barrelLocation.position, 
barrelLocation.rotation);

   // Destroy(tempFlash, 0.5f);
    //  Instantiate(casingPrefab, casingExitLocation.position, 
casingExitLocation.rotation).GetComponent<Rigidbody> 
().AddForce(casingExitLocation.right * 100f);

}

void CasingRelease()
{
     GameObject casing;
    casing = Instantiate(casingPrefab, casingExitLocation.position, 
casingExitLocation.rotation) as GameObject;
     casing.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddExplosionForce(550f, 
(casingExitLocation.position - casingExitLocation.right * 0.3f - 
casingExitLocation.up * 0.6f), 1f);
    casing.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddTorque(new Vector3(0, 
Random.Range(100f, 500f), Random.Range(10f, 1000f)), ForceMode.Impulse);
}


}
```

This script is for joystick movement

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;
using UnityStandardAssets.Utility;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;

namespace UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson
{
[RequireComponent(typeof (CharacterController))]
[RequireComponent(typeof (AudioSource))]
public class FirstPersonController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [HideInInspector]
    public Vector2 RunAxis;

    [SerializeField] private bool m_IsWalking;
    [SerializeField] private float m_WalkSpeed;
    [SerializeField] private float m_RunSpeed;
    [SerializeField] [Range(0f, 1f)] private float m_RunstepLenghten;
    [SerializeField] private float m_JumpSpeed;
    [SerializeField] private float m_StickToGroundForce;
    [SerializeField] private float m_GravityMultiplier;
    [SerializeField] public MouseLook m_MouseLook;
    [SerializeField] private bool m_UseFovKick;
    [SerializeField] private FOVKick m_FovKick = new FOVKick();
    [SerializeField] private bool m_UseHeadBob;
    [SerializeField] private CurveControlledBob m_HeadBob = new 
CurveControlledBob();
       [SerializeField] private LerpControlledBob m_JumpBob = new 
LerpControlledBob();
    [SerializeField] private float m_StepInterval;
    [SerializeField] private AudioClip[] m_FootstepSounds;    // an array of 
footstep sounds that will be randomly selected from.
    [SerializeField] private AudioClip m_JumpSound;           // the sound 
played when character leaves the ground.
    [SerializeField] private AudioClip m_LandSound;           // the sound 
played when character touches back on ground.

    private Camera m_Camera;
    private bool m_Jump;
    private float m_YRotation;
    private Vector2 m_Input;
    private Vector3 m_MoveDir = Vector3.zero;
    private CharacterController m_CharacterController;
    private CollisionFlags m_CollisionFlags;
    private bool m_PreviouslyGrounded;
    private Vector3 m_OriginalCameraPosition;
    private float m_StepCycle;
    private float m_NextStep;
    private bool m_Jumping;
    private AudioSource m_AudioSource;

    // Use this for initialization
    private void Start()
    {
        m_CharacterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        m_Camera = Camera.main;
        m_OriginalCameraPosition = m_Camera.transform.localPosition;
        m_FovKick.Setup(m_Camera);
        m_HeadBob.Setup(m_Camera, m_StepInterval);
        m_StepCycle = 0f;
        m_NextStep = m_StepCycle/2f;
        m_Jumping = false;
        m_AudioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        m_MouseLook.Init(transform , m_Camera.transform);
        Input.multiTouchEnabled = true;
     }


    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update()
    {
        RotateView();
        // the jump state needs to read here to make sure it is not missed
        if (!m_Jump)
        {
            m_Jump = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Jump");
        }

        if (!m_PreviouslyGrounded && m_CharacterController.isGrounded)
        {
            StartCoroutine(m_JumpBob.DoBobCycle());
            PlayLandingSound();
            m_MoveDir.y = 0f;
            m_Jumping = false;
        }
        if (!m_CharacterController.isGrounded && !m_Jumping && 
m_PreviouslyGrounded)
        {
            m_MoveDir.y = 0f;
        }

        m_PreviouslyGrounded = m_CharacterController.isGrounded;
    }


    private void PlayLandingSound()
    {
        m_AudioSource.clip = m_LandSound;
        m_AudioSource.Play();
        m_NextStep = m_StepCycle + .5f;
    }


    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float speed;
        GetInput(out speed);
        // always move along the camera forward as it is the direction that 
it being aimed at
        Vector3 desiredMove = transform.forward*m_Input.y + 
transform.right*m_Input.x;

        // get a normal for the surface that is being touched to move along 
it
        RaycastHit hitInfo;
        Physics.SphereCast(transform.position, m_CharacterController.radius, 
Vector3.down, out hitInfo,
                           m_CharacterController.height/2f, 
Physics.AllLayers, QueryTriggerInteraction.Ignore);
        desiredMove = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(desiredMove, 
hitInfo.normal).normalized;

        m_MoveDir.x = desiredMove.x*speed;
        m_MoveDir.z = desiredMove.z*speed;


        if (m_CharacterController.isGrounded)
        {
            m_MoveDir.y = -m_StickToGroundForce;

            if (m_Jump)
            {
                m_MoveDir.y = m_JumpSpeed;
                PlayJumpSound();
                m_Jump = false;
                m_Jumping = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            m_MoveDir += 
Physics.gravity*m_GravityMultiplier*Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        }
        m_CollisionFlags = 
m_CharacterController.Move(m_MoveDir*Time.fixedDeltaTime);

        ProgressStepCycle(speed);
        UpdateCameraPosition(speed);

        m_MouseLook.UpdateCursorLock();
    }


    private void PlayJumpSound()
    {
        m_AudioSource.clip = m_JumpSound;
        m_AudioSource.Play();
    }


    private void ProgressStepCycle(float speed)
    {
        if (m_CharacterController.velocity.sqrMagnitude > 0 && (m_Input.x != 
0 || m_Input.y != 0))
        {
            m_StepCycle += (m_CharacterController.velocity.magnitude + 
(speed*(m_IsWalking ? 1f : m_RunstepLenghten)))*
                         Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        }

        if (!(m_StepCycle > m_NextStep))
        {
            return;
        }

        m_NextStep = m_StepCycle + m_StepInterval;

        PlayFootStepAudio();
    }


    private void PlayFootStepAudio()
    {
        if (!m_CharacterController.isGrounded)
        {
            return;
        }
        // pick & play a random footstep sound from the array,
        // excluding sound at index 0
        int n = Random.Range(1, m_FootstepSounds.Length);
        m_AudioSource.clip = m_FootstepSounds[n];
        m_AudioSource.PlayOneShot(m_AudioSource.clip);
        // move picked sound to index 0 so it's not picked next time
        m_FootstepSounds[n] = m_FootstepSounds[0];
        m_FootstepSounds[0] = m_AudioSource.clip;
    }


    private void UpdateCameraPosition(float speed)
    {
        Vector3 newCameraPosition;
        if (!m_UseHeadBob)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (m_CharacterController.velocity.magnitude > 0 && 
m_CharacterController.isGrounded)
         {
            m_Camera.transform.localPosition =
                m_HeadBob.DoHeadBob(m_CharacterController.velocity.magnitude 
+
                                  (speed*(m_IsWalking ? 1f : 
m_RunstepLenghten)));
            newCameraPosition = m_Camera.transform.localPosition;
            newCameraPosition.y = m_Camera.transform.localPosition.y - 
m_JumpBob.Offset();
        }
        else
        {
            newCameraPosition = m_Camera.transform.localPosition;
            newCameraPosition.y = m_OriginalCameraPosition.y - 
m_JumpBob.Offset();
        }
        m_Camera.transform.localPosition = newCameraPosition;
    }


    private void GetInput(out float speed)
    {
        // Read input
        float horizontal = RunAxis.x;
        float vertical = RunAxis.y;

        bool waswalking = m_IsWalking;

#if !MOBILE_INPUT
        // On standalone builds, walk/run speed is modified by a key press.
        // keep track of whether or not the character is walking or running
        m_IsWalking = !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift);
#endif
        // set the desired speed to be walking or running
        speed = m_IsWalking ? m_WalkSpeed : m_RunSpeed;
        m_Input = new Vector2(horizontal, vertical);

        // normalize input if it exceeds 1 in combined length:
        if (m_Input.sqrMagnitude > 1)
        {
            m_Input.Normalize();
        }

        // handle speed change to give an fov kick
        // only if the player is going to a run, is running and the fovkick 
is to be used
        if (m_IsWalking != waswalking && m_UseFovKick && 
m_CharacterController.velocity.sqrMagnitude > 0)
        {
            StopAllCoroutines();
            StartCoroutine(!m_IsWalking ? m_FovKick.FOVKickUp() : 
m_FovKick.FOVKickDown());
        }
    }


    private void RotateView()
    {
        m_MouseLook.LookRotation (transform, m_Camera.transform);
    }


    private void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit hit)
    {
        Rigidbody body = hit.collider.attachedRigidbody;
        //dont move the rigidbody if the character is on top of it
        if (m_CollisionFlags == CollisionFlags.Below)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (body == null || body.isKinematic)
        {
            return;
        }
        body.AddForceAtPosition(m_CharacterController.velocity*0.1f, 
hit.point, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }
}
}
```

This one's for Look Around

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;

namespace UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson
{
[Serializable]
public class MouseLook
{
    [HideInInspector]
    public Vector2 LookAxis;

    public float XSensitivity = 2f;
    public float YSensitivity = 2f;
    public bool clampVerticalRotation = true;
    public float MinimumX = -90F;
    public float MaximumX = 90F;
    public bool smooth;
    public float smoothTime = 5f;
    public bool lockCursor = true;


    private Quaternion m_CharacterTargetRot;
    private Quaternion m_CameraTargetRot;
    private bool m_cursorIsLocked = true;

    public void Init(Transform character, Transform camera)
    {
        m_CharacterTargetRot = character.localRotation;
        m_CameraTargetRot = camera.localRotation;
    }


    public void LookRotation(Transform character, Transform camera)
    {
        float yRot = LookAxis.x * XSensitivity;
        float xRot = LookAxis.y * YSensitivity;

        m_CharacterTargetRot *= Quaternion.Euler (0f, yRot, 0f);
        m_CameraTargetRot *= Quaternion.Euler (-xRot, 0f, 0f);

        if(clampVerticalRotation)
            m_CameraTargetRot = ClampRotationAroundXAxis (m_CameraTargetRot);

        if(smooth)
        {
            character.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp 
(character.localRotation, m_CharacterTargetRot,
                smoothTime * Time.deltaTime);
            camera.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp (camera.localRotation, 
m_CameraTargetRot,
                smoothTime * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else
        {
            character.localRotation = m_CharacterTargetRot;
            camera.localRotation = m_CameraTargetRot;
        }

        UpdateCursorLock();
    }

    public void SetCursorLock(bool value)
    {
        lockCursor = value;
        if(!lockCursor)
        {//we force unlock the cursor if the user disable the cursor locking 
helper
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
            Cursor.visible = true;
        }
    }

    public void UpdateCursorLock()
    {
        //if the user set "lockCursor" we check & properly lock the cursos
        if (lockCursor)
            InternalLockUpdate();
    }

    private void InternalLockUpdate()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            m_cursorIsLocked = false;
        }
        else if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            m_cursorIsLocked = true;
        }

        if (m_cursorIsLocked)
        {
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
            Cursor.visible = false;
        }
        else if (!m_cursorIsLocked)
        {
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
            Cursor.visible = true;
        }
    }

    Quaternion ClampRotationAroundXAxis(Quaternion q)
    {
        q.x /= q.w;
        q.y /= q.w;
        q.z /= q.w;
        q.w = 1.0f;

        float angleX = 2.0f * Mathf.Rad2Deg * Mathf.Atan (q.x);

        angleX = Mathf.Clamp (angleX, MinimumX, MaximumX);

        q.x = Mathf.Tan (0.5f * Mathf.Deg2Rad * angleX);

        return q;
    }

   }
}
```

And this one is controlling the scripts

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson;

  public class MyFPSController : MonoBehaviour
{
public FixedJoystick MoveJoystick;
public FixedTouchField TouchField;

// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
{
    var fps = GetComponent<FirstPersonController>();
    fps.RunAxis = MoveJoystick.inputVector;
    fps.m_MouseLook.LookAxis = TouchField.TouchDist;
}
```

Comment: You aren't calling `Shoot()` from anywhere.

Comment: should I put it in Start() ??

Comment: Do you want your gun to fire immediately when your game starts and then never again? No? Then no.

Comment: I just want to move and shoot at the same time(multi touch) as I mentioned above, help me

Comment: Well your issue is that you currently are not calling `Shoot()` anywhere. You need to call `Shoot()`. You need to call it from somewhere that happens every frame and happens based on input. Unless you do those things I cannot diagnose why you can't move and shoot at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `Shoot()` function when you press the trigger, the `Shoot()` function is never used so a bullet is never fired in the first place. i put a little code snippet in with the simpelest way of doing this. the `Shoot()` function is now being executed when the button `Fire1` is pressed. i hope this works for you.

```
void Update()
{
     if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
    {
        Shoot();
    }
}
```